# xcrysden on a macOS Monterey

Tags: quantum-espresso, visualization-software

It seems that Xcrysden is the best software to visualize quantum espresso files.
I've followed the directions from [Xcrysden](http://www.xcrysden.org/Download.html)
and was able to install it on macOS Monterey using [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/xcrysden/). However, I cannot open even the quantum espresso example files under Xcrysden examples.

Was anyone successful in installing it on Macs?

Follow some screenshots of the error messages I'm getting.
As soon as I open it:
[image]

Then, when I try to open the example file

[image]

When I click on error info I get this:

```
dyld[2342]: Library not loaded: 
@rpath/libgfortran.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/xcrysden-
1.6.2/pwi2xsf
  Reason: tried: '/opt/local/lib/xcrysden-
1.6.2/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/opt/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/opt/local/lib/gcc-devel/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin21/12.0.0/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/opt/local/lib/gcc-devel/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin21/12.0.0/../../../libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/opt/local/lib/xcrysden-1.6.2/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/opt/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/opt/local/lib/gcc-devel/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin21/12.0.0/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/opt/local/lib/gcc-devel/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin21/12.0.0/../../../libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file)
```

Comment: Does it give a specific error message? Did you install it from source or use one of the precompiled binaries?

Comment: I used Macports, https://ports.macports.org/port/xcrysden/, I've edited my question with more info about the errors.

Comment: The Macports page says you should be able to test that the installation worked correctly be entering this command in the terminal: `XCRYSDEN_TOPDIR=${prefix}/share/xcrysden-1.6.2 XCRYSDEN_SCRATCH=/tmp ${prefix}/share/xcrysden-1.6.2/tests/make_all_tests.sh`. Also, based on the error messages and checking the files bundled with the Monterrey build, it looks like `libgfortran.5.dylib` is something you need to install separately that isn't included through the macports build of xcrysden.

Comment: @Tyberius I don't have a Mac, but presumably installing gcc (including gfortran) would provide the appropriate libgfortran dynamic library.

Comment: @PhilHasnip after reading your suggestion I installed gfortran and I was still getting the same error message. I then look on how to get the library working on mac and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57207357/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-gfortran-lib-libgfortran-3-dylib-reason-im. It turns out I have libgfortran.5.dylib in many different places but xcrysden wasn't doing a great job in finding it, I then linked it and voila! All is working now!

Comment: @ziulfer Do you maybe want to write up how you solved your issue in an answer?

Comment: It would be nice if you could write your solved solution here, since it would help others. Otherwise, I see no reason to keep this "solved" question open!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can been reopened if OP wants to add the solution they found as an answer.